# Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \” \' \\ )" syntax error

Tags: java, string, variables, ascii

```
print(" $$$$$$\           $$$$$\        $$$$$$\        $$\   $$\ "+newline+
      "$$  __$$\          \__$$ |      $$  __$$\       $$ |  $$ |"+newline+
      "$$ /  $$ |            $$ |      $$ /  $$ |      \$$\ $$  |"+newline+
      "$$$$$$$$ |            $$ |      $$$$$$$$ |       \$$$$  /"+newline+
      "$$  __$$ |      $$\   $$ |      $$  __$$ |       $$  $$< "+newline+
      "$$ |  $$ |      $$ |  $$ |      $$ |  $$ |      $$  /\$$\"+newline+
      "$$ |  $$ |      \$$$$$$  |      $$ |  $$ |      $$ /  $$ |"+newline+
      "\__|  \__|       \______/       \__|  \__|      \__|  \__|"+newline);
```

Hi all ! I am just trying to add ascii art to my games gui, and I get this error? How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The backslash character `\` is an [escape character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) in Java.  The compiler thinks that you are attempting to escape the next character, and `\_` is an invalid escape sequence.  You need to escape the backslash itself.  Replace every `\` with `\\`.

Answer (score 2):

to print a `\` you need to specify `\\` in your string literals.

you don't need to type them all manually. your IDE might have a cool feature witch lets you escape all chars that need to be escaped when pasting to a string literal.

for eclipse it is under:

Window > preferences > java > Editor > typing

then check `Escape text when pasting to a string literal`

Answer (score 0):

You need to double up every backslash, i.e. replace each `\` with `\\`.

The backslash character has special meaning inside Java string literals. It denotes the start of so-called [escape sequences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html). For example, `\n` stands for "new line".

The escape sequence `\\` stands for a single backslash character.

Answer (score 0):

escape the backslashes, basically replace all your backslashes with `\\`

Answer (score 0):

All your backslashes need to be escaped with double backslashes:
e.g.

```
print(" $$$$$\\");
```